# How to adjust insertion of markers in a graph generated by googleway

Tags: r, leaflet, googleway

I would like to insert the same `Markers` from the graph generated by `leaflet` (first graph) in the graph generated by `googleway` (second graph). Note that the route between the two points is generated in the second graph, but it does not have the `Markers` of the first graph. So, can you help me adjust the code below so that the `Markers` appear in the second graph as well?

Code executable below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(googleway)

  set_key( "API KEY")

  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Latitude = c(-23.8, 
  -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.4, -23.5), Longitude = c(-49.6, 
  -49.3, -49.4, -49.8, -49.6, -49.4, -49.2), 
  cluster = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L,3L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
  
  
  df1<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-23.8666666666667, -23.85, -23.45
  ), Longitude = c(-49.6666666666667, -49.35, -49.3), cluster = c(1, 
  2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == 1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Properties==2,]
  
  # Create icon:
  leafIcons <- icons(
    iconUrl = ifelse(df1$cluster,
                     "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/25/25694.png"
    ),
    iconWidth = 30, iconHeight = 40,
    iconAnchorX = 25, iconAnchorY = 12)
  
  html_legend <- "<img src='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/25/25694.png'>"
  
  #Color and Icon for map
  ai_colors <-c("red","gray","blue","orange","green")
  clust_colors <- ai_colors[df$cluster]
  icons <- awesomeIcons(
    icon = 'ios-close',
    iconColor = 'black',
    library = 'ion',
    markerColor =  clust_colors)
```

---

**LEAFLET**

```
  m1<-leaflet(df_spec_clust) %>% addTiles() %>% 
    addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude,icon = leafIcons) %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(leaflet(df_spec_prop) %>% addTiles(), lat=~df_spec_prop$Latitude, lng = ~df_spec_prop$Longitude, icon= icons)
  m1
```

[image]

---

**GOOGLE MAPS**

```
  df2<-google_directions(origin = df_spec_clust[,1:2], 
  destination = df_spec_prop[,2:3], mode = "driving")
    
  df_routes <- data.frame(polyline = direction_polyline(df2))
    
  m2<-google_map() %>%
  add_polylines(data = df_routes, polyline = "polyline")
    
  m2
```

[image]

Comment: does your google map work outside of shiny?

Comment: Yesssss @tospig

Comment: you're not calling `googleway::add_markers()` anywhere.

Comment: @tospig, I tweaked the code without shiny! If you know how to adjust and can answer, I would appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: you need to call `add_markers()` to add markers to the map. You can pipe this after the `add_polylines()` call.